# how to get ansible sequence number of running

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

Here is run.yml and rozofs.yml, I want to get the sequence number of each running.

there is 4 IP address, 90,91,92,93, I want to know where I can get 1,2,3,4 from each running. I am use "echo " to put each IP address, I  want to the sequence number too.

```
$ run.yml

---
- hosts: "{{ store }}"
  remote_user: root
  vars_files:
    - /vars/rozofs.yml
  tasks:
    - name: mount fs
      command: echo "{{ inventory_hostname }}" >> /root/temp.sh
    - name: sequence number
      command:  echo ??? >> /root/temp.sh 

$ rozofs.yml
---
store: 192.168.2.90 192.168.2.91 192.168.2.92 192.168.2.93

$ temp.sh
192.168.2.90
1


$ temp.sh
192.168.2.93
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `store` is a string, split it on space which will give a list of hosts. You can then find the index of the inventory_hostname.

```
- name: mount fs
  shell: echo "{{ inventory_hostname }}" >> /tmp/temp.sh
- name: sequence number
  shell: echo "{{ store.split(' ').index(inventory_hostname) | int + 1 }}"  >> /tmp/temp.sh
```

Comment: where I can find the these usage from your answers? Like "split", it is helpful. Thanks one more!!!!